# What is the meaning of exceptions shown by procdump.exe?

Tags: c++, debugging, procdump

I tried to get a dump file of my application using the ProcDump command as follows:

```
c:\dump>procdump.exe -e -h -ma -o -w  myapp.exe c:\dump

ProcDump v6.00 - Writes process dump files
Copyright (C) 2009-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
With contributions from Andrew Richards

Waiting for process named myapp.exe...

Process:               myapp.exe (1620)
CPU threshold:         n/a
Performance counter:   n/a
Commit threshold:      n/a
Threshold seconds:     n/a
Number of dumps:       1
Hung window check:     Enabled
Exception monitor:     Unhandled
Exception filter:      *
Terminate monitor:     Disabled
Dump file:             c:\dump\myapp_YYMMDD_HHMMSS.dmp


Press Ctrl-C to end monitoring without terminating the process.

[12:23:13] Exception: E0434F4D.COM
[12:23:27] Exception: E0000001
[12:23:38] Exception: 80040155
[12:25:21] Exception: E0434F4D.COM
The process terminated
```

But what is the meaning of the exceptions E0434F4D.COM, E0000001, and 80040155?

Comment: Have you googled them ? And you put your program in a try - catch to catch the exception

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used google for them but I cannot find the answer. I need to know what is the meaning of these exceptions due to the fact that our app are very big...

Comment: Have you tried the "try - catch" ? Besides have you tried the following : 1) edit your app st approx. half of the functions are invoked. If the problem is still present, divide it againg by 2, etc... 2) what is the previous stable version ? reverse back to there and walk up progressively 3) Are you using third parties ? It can be the cause of your troubles. Try replacing them with mock third parties. 4) debug your app by setting break points and walking line by line (no need to enter every function...), 5) etc ...

Comment: After a short google, I found that the cause of your troubles may be from C# .Net or managed C++. You may want to start looking there

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers are exception codes and can e.g. be used in WinDbg to handle exceptions (command is `sxe`).

- `E0434F4D` is a .NET exception

  The characters `.COM` are the ASCII representation of the error code (output from WinDbg):

  ```
  0:017> .formats e0434f4d
  Evaluate expression:
  ...
  Chars:   .COM
  ```
- `80040155` looks like a HRESULT (output from WinDbg):

  ```
  0:017> !error 80040155
  Error code: (HRESULT) 0x80040155 (2147746133) - Interface not registered
  ```